# Accidentally erased an 885 MB partition on my Mac

Tags: macos, partitioning, data-recovery, boot-camp

I opened Disk Utility the other day to reformat an SD card and accidentally erased a partition of my internal SSD. Any idea what I erased?

- 2017 MacBook Pro 15-inch
- Has Boot Camp with latest Windows 10
- Recovery partition boots when I hold <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>
- The partition was not mounted and showed up as `/dev/disk0s4` or something like that until I erased it.
- I cannot modify the size of the partition nor remove it; however, I can reformat it.
- VMware Fusion seems to think I don't have a recovery partition, but I was able to boot into it just fine.
- Everything on the computer seems to be perfectly fine.

My only guess would be a partition used by Boot Camp to install drivers, but I installed Windows 10 a while ago.

Comment: Look at the partition in a previous disk image.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Open up a backup image of the HDD that you have made, and examine the partition as it was previously.

Comment: I have a Time Machine backup, so it only backs up files on Macintosh HD.